# Retrieving data from files in the folder

Tags: optimization, performance, beginner, vba, excel

I am to use VBA code to simply retrieve certain data from all Excel files in certain folder and paste it in working spreadsheet. I am not sure that this is the most efficient (which matters as I would like to learn how to write the most possible efficient codes).

I am using simple copy/paste actions but maybe there are more sophisticated methods (which could help me in the future if for example I would need to get data with certain words in contiguous column in the worksheets, or to order it by date of file creation), or maybe there is better way how to get to the files, or maybe a better to do this and how using forms and tables.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copydata()
Dim script As Object
Dim catalogue As Object
Dim textfile As Object
Dim loadedfile As Workbook
Dim actualfile As Workbook
Dim path As String
Dim column_index As Integer
path = InputBox("Please input path")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set actualfile = ActiveWorkbook
Set script = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set catalogue = script.GetFolder(path)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
   For Each textfile In catalogue.Files

      Workbooks.Open textfile
      Set loadedfile = ActiveWorkbook
      loadedfile.Worksheets(1).Range("D1:D15").Copy
      column_index = actualfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
      actualfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Offset(0, column_index).PasteSpecial
      loadedfile.Close Savechanges:=False

    Next textfile

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a few things I would fix:

find a better way to grab the path - don't let the user type the path manually as he can easily make a typo and you procedure would fail as you're not currently really checking if the path provided is correct/(*exist*). Remember not to ever trust user with their input in your programs.

For example, consider this code which shows a box to select the folder (*note you can even pass the initial path to it by providing a parameter*)

Additionally: If you wanted to point to "My Computer" by default see [**this workaround**](http://vba4all.com/extending-the-functionality-of-vba-forms-by-using-c-com-libraries-specific-openfiledialog-box-pointing-to-my-computer-by-default/) on my blog.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim path As String
    path = GetFolder("") & "\"

    Debug.Print path
End Sub


' strPath is the initial path
Private Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

**Early vs. late binding**

I see you are late binding your objects. There are tons of discussions what is better and why so I am not going to judge here all I can see is that all it takes to get intelli-sense and a better performance is adding references to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` via the Tools -> References in VBE (Visual Basic Editor).

Now, if you combine the tips from above you could get a little bit revised but better version of you code

```
Sub Copydata()

    Dim path As String
    path = GetFolder("") & "\"

    Dim script As FileSystemObject
    Set script = New FileSystemObject

    Dim catalogue As Folder
    Set catalogue = script.GetFolder(path)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False


    Dim textfile As File
    Dim column_index As Integer
    Dim loadedfile As Workbook

    Dim actualfile As Workbook
    Set actualfile = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each textfile In catalogue.Files

        Workbooks.Open textfile
        Set loadedfile = ActiveWorkbook
        loadedfile.Worksheets(1).Range("D1:D15").Copy
        column_index = actualfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
        actualfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Offset(0, column_index).PasteSpecial
        loadedfile.Close Savechanges:=False

    Next textfile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub

' strPath is the initial path
Private Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Great, so now you probably want to eliminate opening each workbook just to copy data. There are [**various ways to pull data from opened and closed workbooks** (*without actually opening them*)](http://vba4all.com/various-ways-to-pull-data-out-of-closed-or-open-workbooks-using-excel-formulas-and-vba/) and I am going to use the ADODB way in your example.

Note, you need to add references to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library` for this to work but the efficiency should increase a lot because you **do not open the files** just to get 15 rows out of them.

Let's start with a very simple example:

Assuming there is a folder `temp` on you `C:\` drive and there is a `file1.xlsm` in it

```
Sub Pull_Data_from_Excel_with_ADODB()

    Dim cnStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "C:\temp\file1.xlsm"

    cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & fileName & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

    query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$D1:D15]"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open query, cnStr, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

    Cells.Clear
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Dim cell As Range, i As Long
    'headers
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

See, this does not open the file and allows you to pull the `D1:D15` from it.

Now if you slightly modify the code to suit your example you get a fully working and efficient code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copydata()

    Dim path As String
    ' retrieve the path to the folder with the files to pull data from
    path = GetFolder("") & "\"

    Dim script As FileSystemObject
    Set script = New FileSystemObject

    Dim catalogue As Folder
    Set catalogue = script.GetFolder(path)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

    Dim cnStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim query As String
    ' SQL query to pull D1:D15 from Sheet1 in each file
    query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$D1:D15]"

    Dim wbFile As Variant

    ' iterate through the files in the folder user selected
    For Each wbFile In catalogue.Files

        ' upate the connection string with path to each file
        cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & wbFile & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

        ' populate a recordset with D1:D15 from each file
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Open query, cnStr, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

        ' Copy data from recordset to range in one go
        Range("A5").Offset(0, Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).CopyFromRecordset rs

        ' close the recordset and free memory
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    Next wbFile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub

' strPath is the initial path
Private Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for very comprehensive answer. I've learned a lot and still have a lot to explore. The code works really fast comparing to Copy/Paste and I hope that this is also safe method. I am wondering what is the rule of order in this method as I know in Copy/Paste the data is pasted with the order based on the file name so I have problem with dates 1 and 10, 2 and 20.. as VBA sees it as string. I am trying to add now 8 last characters from each file name at the top of each column as this is the file's date.

Comment: It is interesting also that I have to use range D4:D36 in query as I want to get range D5:D36 and need 2 empty colums before destination range. Thank you. I can see now that VBA has a lot of sophisticated tools.

Answer (score 4):

You have a HUGE problem, and I'm surprised no one mentioned it. What happens if your code throws an error after you've set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, but before it gets set back to `True`? It *remains off*. You really need to put some error handling in there.

```
Sub copydata()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

'declarations...

'other code...

CleanExit:
    'this code always executes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    'Display message to the user
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Unexpected Error!"
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: great, thanks. error handling is something which I have to take into consideration when writting any code

Answer (score 3):

The lack of proper indentation makes the code pretty hard to read. Also consider declaring the variables as close as possible to their usage, and since [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) is a pretty *bulky* language, vertical whitespace makes it much easier on the eyes:

```
Option Explicit

Sub copydata()

    Dim path As String
    path = InputBox("Please input path")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim actualfile As Workbook
    Set actualfile = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim script As Object
    Set script = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim catalogue As Object
    Set catalogue = script.GetFolder(path)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False

    Dim textfile As Object
    For Each textfile In catalogue.Files

        Workbooks.Open textfile

        Dim loadedfile As Workbook
        Set loadedfile = ActiveWorkbook

        loadedfile.Worksheets(1).Range("D1:D15").Copy

        Dim column_index As Integer
        column_index = actualfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

        actualfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Offset(0, column_index).PasteSpecial          
        loadedfile.Close Savechanges:=False

    Next textfile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub
```

As a procedure, `copydata` should be named `CopyData`, and I find it a bit ironic to see `Option Explicit` right above an *implicitly* `Public` procedure declaration - it might be personal preference, but I find it's best to be explicit about access modifiers and have `Public Sub CopyData()` for a signature.

---

@mehow hit the nail on the head regarding [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) - you don't *need* to *actually* open the workbooks to read `$D$1:$D$15`, I'd warmly recommend following the advice given.

---

The procedure does several things, and could be broken down into multiple steps:

- Get a string from the user, representing a path
- Disable `ScreenUpdating`, `DisplayAlerts` and `AskToUpdateLinks`
- Iterate all files in that folder
- Get the data in range `$D$1:$D$15` of the first worksheet in the workbook
- Write that data in the `actualfile`  workbook
- Enable `ScreenUpdating`, `DisplayAlerts` and `AskToUpdateLinks`

I'd extract a few smaller methods to do one or more of these things - something like this comes to my mind:

```
Private Sub EnableExcelUI(Optional ByVal enabled As Boolean = True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = enabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = enabled
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = enabled
End Sub
```

As was mentioned, you're trusting the user's input.. from an *InputBox* - `InputBox` wasn't designed for this, you could be using an `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136694/1188513) and probably other similar questions, for more information) to get a valid folder from the user, and you'll need to at least verify a file's extension before opening it (be it in Excel or with an ADODB connection) - this could also be extracted into its own `Private Function ValidateExcelFile(ByVal filename As String) As Boolean`.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. That's true that proper indentation makes the code easier to read. Extracting Application.ScreenUpdating, Application.DisplayAlerts, Application.AskToUpdateLinks (disabled, enabled) seems to 
speed up the code, but maybe this is only my impression because my sample was not big. Thanks.